# Generic return type for index signature in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Here's the problem

```
interface Prop<T> {
   value: T;
}

class Property<T> implements Prop<T> {
   value: T;
   constructor(value: T) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}

class Node {
   this.props: { [index: string]: Prop<T> } // how do you define T?
}
```

`T` can't be defined at class level here as needs as the intended use would be along the lines of

```
const strProp = node.props<string>['strProp'];
const numProp = node.props<number>['numProp'];
```

In other words, a `Node` can have various property types attached to it.

There doesn't appear to be anything in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) about this (or perhaps I'm just not seeing it). Basically what I'm really looking for here is a generic indexer, for example:

```
this.props: <T>{ [index: string]: Prop<T> }
```

Does it exist?

*Disclaimer - I'm not looking for workarounds, I understand there are ways around this but I'd like to know whether or not the support is there (I couldn't see any proposals or outstanding issues on the repo for this). There were some similar issues but nothing specific to this particular scenario.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in TypeScript only functions (including methods) and types (classes, interfaces, type aliases) can be generic.

---

Additionally, it doesn't look like what you're asking for actually makes much sense.  To see why, let's look at one of those workarounds you're not necessarily interested in:

```
abstract class Node {
  abstract propsGetter<T>(index: string): Prop<T>;
}
```

Here we define a getter method which takes a type parameter `T` and a `string` parameter and returns a value of type `Prop<T>`.  This is more or less the  equivalent of an indexed property.  Notice that it is the *caller*, not the *implementer* of this method that specifies both the type `T` and `index`.

You would, I suppose, call it like this:

```
declare const node: Node;
const strProp = node.propsGetter<string>('strProp');
const numProp = node.propsGetter<number>('numProp');
```

But wait, nothing stops you from calling it like this:

```
const whatProp = node.propsGetter<string>('numProp'); // no error
```

If you were expecting that the compiler would somehow know that the `'numProp'` parameter would return a `Prop<number>` and that there would be an error, the compiler would disappoint you.  The signature of `propsGetter` promises that it will return a `Prop<T>` for whatever value of `T` the caller wants, no matter what the `index` parameter is.

Unless you describe for the compiler some relationship between the type of `index` (presumably some collection of string literals) and the type of `T`, there's no type safety here.  The type parameter does nothing for you.  You might as well remove the type parameter and just do something like:

```
abstract class Node {
  abstract propsGetter(index: string): Prop<{}>;
}
```

which returns a `Prop<{}>` value you have to type check or assert:

```
const strProp = node.propsGetter('strProp') as Prop<string>; // okay
const numProp = node.propsGetter('numProp') as Prop<number>; // okay
```

This is just as non-type-safe as the above but at least it is explicit about it.

```
const whatProp = node.propsGetter('numProp') as Prop<string>; // still no error but it's your responsibility
```

And then since we don't need the generic parameter you can indeed use an indexer:

```
class Node {
   props: { [index: string]: Prop<{}> } 
}
```

---

Recall,

> Unless you describe for the compiler some relationship between the type of `index` (presumably some collection of string literals) and the type of `T`, there's no type safety here.

Do you have some kind of way to tell the compiler which property keys should return which property types?  If so, this is looking like you don't actually want a pure `string`-indexed type but a standard object of the sort:

```
abstract class Node {
  props: {
    strProp: Prop<string>,
    numProp: Prop<number>,
    // ... others ...
    [otherKeys: string]: Prop<{}> // default
  }
}
```

Maybe one of those meets your use case... not that you care, as your disclaimer disclaims.  In the case that you don't care, please ignore everything after my first sentence.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: *"This is more or less the equivalent of an indexed property"* - yeah it is, and this is what I currently have (which was the jist of "no workarounds" comment). However, the reason for wanting support on the property itself is really just to avoid having to add a wrapper func as I'm using an object for key-value lookup internally.

Comment: *"If you were expecting that the compiler would somehow know that the 'numProp' parameter would return a `Prop<number>` and that there would be an error, the compiler will disappoint you"* - that would be nice, and with languages like C#, IIRC, you'd get that at runtime. However, given how flexible JS is in terms of type coercian I understand why that's probably a bridge too far at the minute. I'm just exploring TypeScript at the minute and seeing where the boundaries are.